# How to limit the amount of RAM for cmake on raspberrypi?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, ram

I am trying to compile a project ([tdbot](https://github.com/vysheng/tdbot)) on raspberry pi but when the compilation reaches 50% the available RAM is exhausted and the OS (*Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) running on a pi v3, 1GB RAM)* kills off the compiler thread which results in an error:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/td/telegram/AnimationsManager.cpp.o
make[3]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:341: recipe for target 'td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/telegram-bot.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/telegram-bot.dir/rule] Terminated
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'telegram-bot' failed
make: *** [telegram-bot] Terminated
./build.sh: line 1:  9784 Terminated              make -j 1 telegram-bot
```

The same project compiles fine on linux and macos. The exact percentage and file name where the compiler process is killed can vary between builds, i.e. it can be 50% or 51%, etc.

I've configured an 8GB swap file by setting `CONF_SWAPSIZE=8192` in `/etc/dphys-swapfile` (memory usage while at 50% compilation).

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           875M        825M         30M          0B         20M         16M
Swap:          8.0G        828M        7.2G
```

But even with 8GB swap memory the compiler process is still killed off at 50%.

I've googled for hours trying to find any compile flags for make or cmake that will reduce the RAM requirement but couldn't find anything.

I've also used `make -j 1` in order to only use one kernel but it did not help either.

Any other way to make the compilation succeed?

Comment: How about cross-compilation on your main computer, and then install the built program onto the Pi?

Comment: And besides, how do you know the problem is because of memory usage and not some other problem? How do you measure the memory usage of the build process? If you run a verbose build (by doing e.g. `make VERBOSE=1`), do you get more information then?

Comment: the cmake error indicates that the child thread was killed off; so it is obviously a ram issue; and that was confirmed by other github issues and similar error reports that came up while googling

Comment: I looked into cross-compiling, specifically as per https://desertbot.io/blog/how-to-cross-compile-for-raspberry-pi and https://bitbucket.org/mitchallen/pi-cross-compile and couldn't get those to work because I got lost in the dependencies and configurations.

Comment: *"it is obviously a ram issue"* - no, it is not. child process can be killed because of 1000s of other reasons.

Comment: any pointers for identifying the root cause? i'm not a c++ dev so don't have much knowledge of the toolkit

Comment: You're better off cross compiling. Even if you solved this issue with Cmake, it's going to bomb at linking, or take several days due to page thrashing.

Comment: Use the latest LLVM/Clang instead of GCC and use as linker gold or lld instead of ld. The former have in general a smaller memory footprint compared to the latter.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits: do you have a description of a cross-compiling setup at hand which works for you? either for linux/ubuntu or mac?